# Is it possible to pull dynamic items Status report from Processbook without opening progran?

Tags: osisoft

EDIT [Closed]

I need to make multiple Status Reports from multiple Files. TO do that i wanted to make a script that creates the CSV from the Status Report without opening the actual Program ProcessBook. Is it even possible or do i have to write a "mimick my click" script instead?

With mouseclicks i'd have to click Save to File to create the CSV.

Environment is OSISoft PI ProcessBook with .pi Files

[image: Status Report can be saved to File as CSV]

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to without opening process book .What are your trying to use this for (are you just wanting to get the status of tags)?

Comment: Speaking as a systems integrator specialising in OSIsoft products, I think you're probably trying to extend ProcessBook beyond its limits - for reporting you should be using some combination of PI AF, PI Vision or PI Datalink. PI ProcessBook is now officially retired and is being phased out permanently, so don't work too hard at trying to get a polished finish on a legacy tool.

Comment: Thanks @SteveTaylor will try that

Comment: No problem - I'm not sure what organisation you're with or where you're based, but whoever supports your PI System should be able to help, or help connect you with OSIsoft support. There are also many specialists around in various Systems Integrator companies - I'm with ITI Group, but there are also DAI, Wipro, Infosys, KBC and others. If you're a keen developer, you may be able to find other options yourself by leveraging PISDK/AFSDK or OSIsoft.Powershell libraries. But if you haven't explored PI AF that's the first avenue to explore, and may unlock other opportunities you haven't considered.